# Import text file with tab delimiter and missing data

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL. I need to import a text file with tab delimiter. And there are many missing data in the file. When I tried to import the file, there is an error message 
""ERROR:  missing data for column "column71" 
CONTEXT:  COPY real_acct_2005, line 11526:......."

I checked the column 71 and row 11526 in Access, but still don't understand what the problem is. Your help would be very much appreciated!

[Here is the screenshot of the column 71 and row 11526 in Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E71Qx.jpg)

My code is:
CREATE TABLE real_acct_2005(
    Column1 text,
    ......
    Column70 text,
    Column71 text
);

COPY real_acct_2005 FROM 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\real_acct.txt' with delimiter E'\t';

Comment: 0) I can't read your screenshot. Please put a relevant portion of the file in text in the question. 1) Maybe field71 IS NULL, and some editor has removed the final trailing `\t` that should precede it (editors sometimes silently remove trailing space). Another possibility is CR/CR/LF problems (since you appear to be on a MS-box)

Answer (score 0):

Search for \ and replace it with \\ and then try copying

Comment: Thank you! I tried to remove the \ from that record or replace\ with \\, the system returns a new error message. Maybe the change has an impact on the structure of the text file? Also, it takes a while to open the text file with notepad and make changes because each is 605 MB. NOTICE:  table "real_acct_2005" does not exist, skipping
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa5
CONTEXT:  COPY real_acct_2005, line 47372
********** Error **********

Comment: I don't actually need column 71. Is it possible to skip import this column so I can avoid the error?